# find command always returns 1

Tags: batch-file, tortoisesvn

```
find "a" "C:\a.txt" && (
    echo found >CON
) || (
    echo not found >CON
)
echo %errorlevel% >CON
if errorlevel 1  (
    echo not found >CON
) else (
    echo found >CON
)
```

This is my tortoisesvn local pre-commit hook. It always echos "not found" for me.

What's wrong with it?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure about the CR/LF thing. I changed it to CR (Mac) and LF (Unix) using Notepad++ and in each case it was found correctly...

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Agreed does work here. Even if saved with utf16 or utf8 format (with notepad++)

Comment: Have you tried specifying the full path to `find` as it is an external command?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I have to use `findstr`.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14940687)

Comment: Isn't this the complete answer to my question?

Comment: This could use [more explanation to avoid deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/175564).